# How to bind Entry (from login) to masterdetailpage in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

This is the code behind my MasterDetailPage (MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {       
        public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }

        public string Get_item;
        public MainPage(string SelectedItem)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Get_item = SelectedItem;

            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            SetValue(NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty, false);
            // Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home_red.png", TargetType = typeof(Main) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Settings", Icon = "setting_violet.png", TargetType = typeof(Settings) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Records", Icon = "blue_database.png", TargetType = typeof(HomePageX) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "About", Icon = "black_about.png", TargetType = typeof(test) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "LogOut", Icon = "yellow_logout.png", TargetType = typeof(Login) });
            // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
            // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Main)));
        }
    }
```

I have this Grid in my MainPage.xaml:

```
               <Grid>
                    <Image Source="peach_gradient.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                    <StackLayout>
                        <forms:AnimationView x:Name="animationView"                                                  
                                                 Animation="diamond.json" 
                                                 Loop="True" 
                                                 AutoPlay="True"
                                                 HeightRequest="150"
                                                 WidthRequest="150"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Get_item}" 
                               TextColor="White" 
                               FontSize="Large"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
```

This is my code for my Login.xaml:

```
                        <ScrollView>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20,80,20,0" RowSpacing="20">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="EntryLoginUsername"
                                           Placeholder="Username"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                           PlaceholderColor="WhiteSmoke"/>

                                    <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="EntryLoginPassword"
                                           Placeholder="Password"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           IsPassword="True"
                                           TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                           PlaceholderColor="WhiteSmoke"/>

                                    <Button Text="Login"
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>                                    
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
```

this is my Code behind my login page (Login.xaml.cs):

```
public void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)//LOGIN!
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            var loginquery = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.Username.Equals(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && u.Password.Equals(EntryLoginPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(EntryLoginUsername.Text));
        }
```

if I run this code, the Label Text="{Binding Get_item}" in my main page is just blank, I want to implement it like this:

[image]

the text in the entry(from the Login page) should be placed here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only bind to public properties.  `Get_item` is not a public property

```
public string Get_item;
```

change it to this

```
public string Get_item { get; set; }
```

you also need to set the `BindingContext` for your page

```
this.BindingContext = this;
```